# How to move a div inside another using function()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to move the position of a div from where it is created in my php document and move it to another location in the file.

I want to create a div around line 11, and then use the variables created in each row and then move the newly created div inside: *div class="selector">*

This is what my script looks like currently:

```html
 <div class="selector" onclick="showChannels()";><div id="channel">hi</div></div>
        <div id="cCwrapper">
        <?php include 'clientConnections.php';?>
         <?php
            $sql = "SELECT icon, pageName, Channel FROM clientconnections";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo 
            '<div class="itemWrapper" onclick="selectChannels()">
            <div class="iconWrapper">
            <img src="'.
            $row["icon"].
            '" style="height: 16px; height: 16px;>
            </div> <!--closes icon wrapper-->
            <div class="channelWrapper">'.
            $row["pageName"]. 
            '</div> <!-- closes channel wrapper-->
            </div> <!--closes item wrapper-->
            ';
        }
            } else {
            echo "Oops! We can't find your connected accounts!";
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Hard to make much sense out of what you are asking or trying to do

Comment: Amended the post, hopefully it makes more sense now?

Comment: Still not clear..

Comment: No, not really. Show expected results and please don't expect us to count lines

Comment: try this : http://jsbin.com/suvuwuzutu/edit?html,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function showChannels(){
  $("#selected_new_element").html($(this)[0].outerHTML); // moving div.selector element inside #selected_new_element (replace html value with this one)
  $("#selected_new_element").append($(this)[0].outerHTML); // appending div.selector element inside #selected_new_element
  $(this).remove(); // remove current element, for "moving" element
}
```

### Some good reference :

1. http://api.jquery.com/html/
2. http://api.jquery.com/append/
3. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML
4. https://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: This worked a treat! Thanks!